# Put newest database item on top

Tags: php, mysql

I've made a microblog system (like Twitter) using PHP and MySQL. Every time someone posts an item it includes the UNIX timestamp in the database. But my question is, how do i get the newest item on top of the page, the second to newest as second, etc? So basically, the one with the 'highest' timestamp on top of the page, the one with a bit 'less' timestamp under that.
This is what I got (I know mysql_ functions are deprecated):

```
<?php
/*Database test.
© 2013 Sydcul. All rights reserved.

To set the database settings, use the 'install' directory*/

include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/test/config.inc.php');

$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);

mysql_select_db($database, $connection);

$messages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `" . $prefix . "microblog`");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($messages))
  {
    $names = mysql_query("SELECT first_name,last_name FROM `" . $prefix . "data` WHERE id='" . $row['id'] . "'");
    $name = mysql_fetch_assoc($names);
    $fullname = $name['first_name'] . " " . $name['last_name'];
    echo "<h2>Posted by " . $row['id'] . " (" . $fullname . ")</h2>";
    echo $row['message'] . "<br><br>";
  }
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Please explain how to do it, instead of only giving me code, otherwise I and the other people on stackoverflow can't learn from it :)

Comment: So... You'd like to **order** your resultset **by** timestamp? In a **desc** ending order?

Comment: You should be storing date as a datetime column not a UNIX time stamp (epoch I am assuming).

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: I already knew that. Or is this an automatic thing?

Comment: I'm sure it's not automatic, but I'm positive some users just search for everything with the mysql tag and spam this message everywhere they can. It's tedious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) in your SQL

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY datefield DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have an auto_incrementing ID field, fetch your data and ORDER BY `ID` or else if you have a DateField, Order by that in a descending order

```
ORDER BY `ID` DESC
```

as simple as that.

Comment: Good answer. But John Conde was faster ;)